# index unique strange behaviour

Tags: spring, mongodb, indexing, unique, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to spring data and mongo, so may be my pbm is something realy easy...

I've got a simple document `User` with an ID `object ID` and a login `String` with annotation `@Indexed(unique = true)`.

User are saved using `MongoOperations : mongoOperations.save(user);`

I've created a simple unit test to check that duplicate login are rejected. It seems to work fine.

After that, I've added an other test to check that an unknown user is not found...

What seens very strange to me is since this new test is executed before the first one, the first one fails : 2 Users with same login are inserted in DB.

If i check directly with mongo client i can see that 2 objects with the same login are stored.

```
db.user.find({})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5904f59c5ea29c288c593280"),
    "_class" : "com.test.User", "login" : "toto"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5904f59c5ea29c288c593282"), 
    "_class" : "com.test.User", "login" : "toto"
}
```

Is there any explanation to that ?

I'm using:

- mongo 3.4.3
- spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.2.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 1.5.2.RELEASE

Please find below some part of my code (I hope I didn't miss any important things).

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/mydb
```

The Document User

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    public String login;

    private String pass;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String login, String pass) {
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

My Junit test :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserController.class })
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class TestUserController {

    @Autowired
    private DbInitialisatioController dbInitController;

    @Autowired
    private UserController controller;

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mongoTemplate.getDb().dropDatabase();

        // Should not be usefull, but without that call test is not successfull
        dbInitController.init();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindUnknownUser() {
        Assert.assertNull("User bob should be null as does not exists", controller.findByLogin("bob"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser_ErrorSavingTwice() throws MyException {
        User user = new User("toto", "pass");

        controller.createUser(user);

        try {
            controller.createUser(user);
            Assert.fail("User must not be saved twice");
        } catch (MyException e) {
            Assert.assertEquals(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR, e.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

The "controller" it's role is to perform access to DB.

```
@Component
public class UserController {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Autowired
    ProfilController profilController;

    public User findByLogin(String login) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("login").is(login));

        return mongoOperations.findOne(query, User.class);
    }

    public void createUser(User user) throws MyException {
        if (user.getId() != null) {
            throw new MyException(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR, "could not saveNewUser for existing user");
        }

        logger.info("Creating user {}", user);

        try {
            mongoOperations.save(user);
            logger.info("Created {}", user);
        } catch (org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException e) {
            throw new MyException(ErrorCode.LOGIN_ALREADY_EXITS, user.login);
        }
    }

    // ... some other methods
}
```

This class should not exits but without it test fails

```
@Component
public class DbInitialisatioController {

final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Autowired
    UserController userController;

    /**
    * Note I don't understand why I need to create indexes here. I was expecting that Indexed annotation in User and Profil would do the same...
    */
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Initializing DB");
        mongoOperations.indexOps(User.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("login", Direction.ASC).unique());
        mongoOperations.indexOps(Profile.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("login", Direction.ASC).unique());
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check in the DB if the index is actually set to unique. If not, there is something wrong in the code. In this case. We would need to see more code!

Comment: You're right. Index is not present in mongo. Now I've added it ising : `mongoOperations.indexOps(User.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("login", Direction.ASC).unique()); ` So now the question is why does the 1th test seems to work when it runs alone whitout out the index on the DB ? Does spring tries to handle index by himself (in cache or something like that ) ?

Comment: Because there is probably something wrong in your code ;)
The annotation should be enough, but if is for some reason not handled in the first test, the second might not be allowed to overwrite it. If you want more help with this. Post your code.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I've edited the post to add few code samples. I hope I didn't forget any thing usefull.

Comment: Looking through your code I think you are not using a repository. I'm not familiar with MongoOperations but I think the repo implements this for you. I would recommend creating a UserRepository: `public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String>` see this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/